# Reference on diffeomorphisms between subspaces of ${\mathbb R}^n$

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I am looking for a basic reference on [Diffeomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism).

I am mainly interested on checking conditions to tell whether or not given two spaces $M,N \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$, there exists at least one diffeomorphism between them. For example, I don't know if there exists a diffeomorphism between 
$[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$. As well as some other classical results on diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Diffeomorphism usually includes heomeomorphism; $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ are not homeomorphic, e.g., by compactness, so they cannot be diffeomorphic.

Comment: @user99680 Thanks, that is a great pointer. Very appreciated. Do you know of any reference in this line?

Comment: Sorry, not clear on your question: do you mean to ask how to show that compactness is a topological property?

Comment: @user99680 Sorry, I didn't provide enough context on my problem since I tried to be concise. I want to analyse some general changes of variable between functions defined on subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ but, in order to do this, I need to check for which pairs of subsets this actually makes sense. Then, I need to check if there exists at least one diffeomorphism between them.

Comment: Let me think it through more carefully and see if I can come up with something better suited.

Comment: @user99680 Thanks, I will check later. I have accepted your answer since it was very helpful already.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll see if I can think of something else.

Comment: @DiscoStu If you ask a new question with more specific examples of spaces, you're likely to get more help.  This question is a bit too broad to yield anything but the most general suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only general result I can think of is that of the inverse function theorem :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem , which tells you about the existence of a local diffeomorphism if the differential of the map is invertible as a matrix. And, of course, you first need for the two subspaces to be homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you, as I mentioned, the connection with homeomorphisms is of great help. Before accepting, could you please point out a book to read further?

Comment: Sure: Guillemin's book: http://books.google.com/books/about/Differential_Topology.html?id=4CKDyp0ph-cC is pretty good, and it has online solutions:http://vision.caltech.edu/~kchalupk/guillemin_pollack.html . John M. Lee's "Intro to Smooth Manifolds is also pretty good.